# Aurelia - Reference custom element view model inside slot

Tags: javascript, aurelia

If I have a custom element like this:

```
export class mycomponent {
    constructor() {
         this.name = 'John Doe';
    }
}

<template>
     My component
     <slot></slot>
</template>
```

And use this component inside another view (I registered the custom element globally):

```
<template>
    <mycomponent>
        Test
        ${name}
    </mycomponent>
</template>
```

Is it possible to access the view model of `mycomponent` in this scope? Like printing out its property `name` for example?

**EDIT**
So here is my final solution: [gist my solution](https://gist.run/?id=84c9af42863a5c368c8f977e39e884d5)

I put the replaceable part inside my custom element:

```
<template>
  <template replaceable part="content"></template>
</template>
```

and then processContent attribute on the view model:

```
import { processContent } from 'aurelia-framework';

@processContent(replacePart)
export class MyComponent {
  name = "John Doe";
}

function replacePart(compiler, resources, node){
    node.innerHTML = `<template replace-part="content">${node.innerHTML}</template>`;
    return true;
}
```

Like this it works more like a slot with cleaner syntax:

```
<h4>Component 1</h4>
<my-component>
    <div>One name</div>
    <strong>${name}</strong>
</my-component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it cannot be achieved using slots.

However, Aurelia has a feature called `replaceable parts`: [[Blog post]](http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-template-parts/). This might be a better fit for your requirements.

Demo: https://gist.run/?id=dcffe2afcb1eee1777e9b0d9f7366d28

**Edit:** HUB docs: [[Cheat Sheet / Template Parts]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/9)

Comment: Nice answer. Easy way to accomplish my goal. I considered to try and fetch the content out of the slot and then compile it manually with view compiler but that would maybe make the problem more complicated than necessary. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, `replaceable` is an Aurelia specific concept, but does provide more functionality when it's needed.

Comment: @AshleyGrant: It's a remarkable feature indeed. I was going to say that it isn't documented on the HUB, but found it in the Cheat Sheet. :) Updated the answer to have that official source as well.